# Authorization in lightswitch

Tags: authorization, lightswitch-2013

I got a good link on Authorization of lightswitch

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2013/12/18/beginning-lightswitch-in-vs-2013-part-5-may-i-controlling-access-with-user-permissions.aspx

But I don't know how each use user is assigned to a  role

How can we assign a user to a role.?

How each role can be assigned to different  permissions?

Using lightswich 2013 with html client

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the permissions to roles and the users to roles from within the Lightswitch Silverlight Desktopclient. You must be the administrator of the application.
From within the HTML client this is not possible out of the box.
Michael Washington, a Lightswitch guru, has a turnaround for this extending the Lightswitch application to an [MVC asp. net application](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3281/An-HTML-MVC-LightSwitch-Security-Administration.aspx).